# Powering a peltier element

Tags: peltier

[image]

I am trying to design a hot/cold cup holder using a Peltier device. I am using a DPDT switch to switch the current flow. I am running from a 12 V 2.0A  power source for testing. The issue is when the Peltier is connected the 12 V fan loses power and doesn't run at max speed. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: (1) How your toy is connected to the 12V? https://www.aliexpress.com/w/wholesale-peltier-module.html. (2) Can we have a pic?

Comment: What's the current draw? What's your schematic? What is the votlage when the peltier is connected and running?

Comment: Or show us a video? https://www.google.com/search?q=peltier+diy&oq=peltier+diy&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i61.4609j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#fpstate=ive&vld=cid:97a2fd73,vid:clZsykBt4YA

Comment: The voltage drop is +/- 2V

Comment: Please write what Pletier element (link to datasheet) you are using. Most Peltiers run at very low voltages and high currents.

Answer (score 2):

Because you're not giving any information on what devices you're using (neither power supply nor peltier element) everything written here can only be very general.

**What's happening:**

Your fan stops because your peltier draws more current than your power pupply can deliver thus the power supply output either drops to a lower voltage or the power supply switches off entrirely when overloaded (without the information what power supply you're using, this is impossible to say).

Peltier elements normally run an low volatges with high currents.

**How to Solve:**

Read the Datasheet of your peltier. Find out at what voltage and current you want to run it and find a solution to deliver that power.

Comment: I just found the data sheet, it says 6A 12V 60 WATT so it looks like the power supply isnt enough, I tried to run a capacitor to compensate but they just exploded.

Comment: Why the caps exploded I can't tell you (except if you reversed the polarity) but They can't "make" current. If your peltier needs 6A at 12V you need a power supply that can deliver that. Also make sure that the heat spreader with fan can get the whole heat (72W electrical + heat transfer, let's say 80W) away otherwise your peltier will overhiet and be destroyed.